# $\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$-vector space isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$-module isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Let $A,B$ be $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. We can view them as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Suppose that there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module isomorphism $\phi$ between $A$ and $B$. Then can we have a natural $\mathbb{Q}$(or even $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$)-vector space isomorphism between $A$ and $B$ from $\phi$?

I think at least we can have $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space isomorphism.

For example, Let $a\in A$ and denote $\frac{1}{n}a=\alpha\in A$ for some natural number $n$. Let $\phi$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module isomorphism from $A$ to $B$. Then, we have

$\phi(a)=\phi(n\alpha)=n\phi(\alpha)=n\phi(\frac{1}{n}a)$.

Thus, $\phi(\frac{1}{n}a)$ has to be $\frac{1}{n}\phi(a)$. Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field of fraction of $\mathbb{Z}$, we may have $\phi(\frac{m}{n}a)=\frac{m}{n}\phi(a)$ for all $a\in A$ and $\frac{m}{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Am I right?

Now, I am struggling to extend to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ vector space isomorphism.

Comment: I think your dream is unrealistic (the parts about going beyond $\Bbb{Q}$). After all, $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^2$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\Bbb{Q}$. Both have continuum dimension. The question is interesting (+1), but I also think it has been covered earlier on the site.

Comment: No, use a Hamel basis to construct lots of automorphisms of $\mathbb R / \mathbb Q$.

Comment: If you add continuity for $\phi$ then you're getting somewhere. (for $\mathbb R$-linearity, anyway)

Comment: If you consider $A$ and $B$ as complex manifolds, assuming they are finite-dimensional, then a $\Bbb Z$-linear map is $\Bbb C$-linear iff it is holomorphic.

Comment: For $\Bbb R$-linearity, measurable is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument that $\mathbb{Z}$-linear implies $\mathbb{Q}$-linear is correct but it's not possible to go beyond this. In fact assuming the axiom of choice $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}^2$, for example, are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces (since they both have the same dimension, namely $|\mathbb{R}|$).

On the other hand, it's consistent with ZF that [every homomorphism between Polish groups is automatically continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536075/fxy-fxfy-but-f-lambda-x-neq-lambda-fx/4536192#4536192), and in particular that every homomorphism between *finite-dimensional* real or complex vector spaces is automatically continuous. If this is true then any $\mathbb{Z}$-linear isomorphism between finite-dimensional real or complex vector spaces is automatically $\mathbb{R}$-linear, so in the real case we're done, and in the complex case they have the same real dimension and hence the same complex dimension, so there is some other $\mathbb{C}$-linear isomorphism between them.